# ionic 4 ion-item display items by columns and not in rows

Tags: css, angular, ionic4

I am having some problem with ion-item, it's displaying all items inside it in a column, but I need to display them in 2 different rows. Any idea? I can't understand how ion-item is working "behind the scene". I try with changing the **display** **property** of ion-item but nothing.  This is my code, for the moment it's displayed in only 1 column, I would like to display them in 2 separate rows.

```
        <ion-item lines="none" ...>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-icon [name]="item.icon"></ion-icon>
          </ion-row>
          <ion-row>
            <ion-label>
              {{p.title}}
            </ion-label>
          </ion-row>
        </ion-item>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can find list here https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/list

Comment: I tried your code, for me its working fine. Can you create sample stackblitz of your code?